# RDS Gateway Slow Initial Connection

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote, remote-desktop-services

I've setup a Win2k8 R2 RDS Gateway.  It works great but the initial connection takes 10-20 seconds.  I've had a hard time finding troubleshooting ideas for the problem.  Anyone have any suggestions on where to start or common issues?

Answer (score 0):

DNS is my guess!

Comment: What part of the name resolution process would cause it to be slow but not to fail?

Comment: Reverse dns perhaps..
ive seen this problem before ( waiting until it fails ) 
im not exactly sure.. but its where i would start looking

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem and ended up virtualizing Remote Desktop Gateway on its own VM under Hyper-V. We isolated it away from our other server functions, and it sped it up as far as connections go.

We recently installed a VPN (Remote Access Server role) for sstp traffic, and we noticed our VPN connection happens a bit quicker than the RDP one through SSL.

Our advice to you would be to build a box in a lab environment with only this service loaded and the appropriate certificate to see if something else is perhaps slowing it down.